нужна ли запятая после слова лицам
Ответственным лицам установить лимиты по уровню платежей по статьям затрат.

Приветствую вас на форуме, oxot nik! Именно запятая после слова "лицам", конечно же, не нужна. Но предложение может иметь двоякий смысл. Теоретически.

Это предложение? А где предикат и субъект действия хотя бы в одном смысле?
